# How to make Sublime Text to wrap line between any two letters?

Tags: sublime-text-3, sublime-text

Sublime Text 3 can only wrap between words (which separated by space or other punctuations) by its default setting.

I'd like something like ["word-break: break-all;"](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp) in css, or say let lines may break between any two letters.
It would be more convenient when writing Chinese characters documents.

I guess this can be done with setting new syntax, but don't know how to do it exactly.